# Sending a File as a Request

Tags: java, request, serversocket

How can I sent a html `file` as a HTTP request using a Server Socket?

Please note that it is a file I would like to send as a request.
Thank you

Comment: Do you understand that you don't just "send a file as an HTTP request"?  An HTTP request can contain a file.  Also, a `ServerSocket` implies that the file would be a response to a request.

Comment: yes i just found out. Sorry but cant delete it as there are a answer so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out Apache's FileUpload project.

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/